# How to create a 64-bit-DLL in Delphi 10.4 and call it from python/julia

Tags: python, delphi, dll

I have a Delphi library that I want to compile to a DLL (`PyMinMod_TRANS.dll`) that can be called from another programming language like Python or Julia. When compiling it from RADStudio Delphi 10.4 to Windows 32 Bit and calling it with 32-bit-Python 2 via

```py
import ctypes as ct
PyMinMod_TRANS = ct.WinDLL('D:/Users/pjuergen/Dateien/git-repositories/remod-test/PyMinMod_TRANS.dll')
```

everything works as expected.

However if I compile it to Windows 64 Bit and try to call it from 64-bit-Python 3 (or Julia) I get an Error stating
**WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found**

I opened `PyMinMod_TRANS.dll` with Dependency Walker and I get a lot of missing dependencies, lots of them starting either with `API-MS-WIN` or `EXT-MS` and also `PYTHON27.DLL`, `HVSIFILETRUST.DLL` and `IESHIMS.DLL`.

[Report from Dependency Walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clLIV.png)

However this doesn't help me to fix the problem :)

The Delphi library that I want to compile uses the packages `System.SysUtils`,  `PyAPI`, `math`, `classes`, `vcl.FileCtrl`.

I figured out that the PyAPI-File comes from this source: https://wiki.freepascal.org/Developing_Python_Modules_with_Pascal

Changing the line

```pascal
PythonLib = 'python27.dll';
```

to

```pascal
PythonLib = 'python37.dll';
```

leads to another error
**OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found**,
but the report from Dependency Walker looks pretty much the same.

What can I do to be able to load the DLL both in Python 3 and Julia (64bit)?

Comment: Loading a Delphi DLL in Python and Julia is not a big deal. Just create a DLL, and compile it, making sure you use the 64 bit target. The problem is likely to be related to dependencies for your DLL, which we know nothing of. Dependency Walker is not reliable with modern Windows versions. You need to debug your own DLL. We can't do that.

Comment: Is the error you get **WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found** generated by python code or by DLL code? I guess python code. It is likely that the DLL is not where you expect it. Use ProcessMonitor to see what python tries to load and which dependency is fetched. If the error comes from the DLL code, then debug the DLL using Delphi debugger. If you don't know how to debug a DLL, ask a new question.

Comment: This question needs more focus.  Do you have a test application to verify the DLL's function?  If not, make one and test your DLL to make sure it works as expected.  If that works then your DLL is fine and this is strictly a configuration problem with python/julia (ie: path to the DLL is incorrect).  If the DLL does not work in the test application, then this has nothing to do with python/julia - either way, you can narrow down this problem before making a question of it.

Comment: Well, the question is "How to create a 64 bit DLL in Delphi ...". I have an application that uses the Delphi-Code which works both in 32 and 64 bit. I also have an application in Python 2 (32 bit) that loads the 32-bit-DLL and works as expected. The problem is: How do I get Delphi/RADStudio to create a 64 bit DLL that also works as expected?
As Python-Delphi-Interface I am using what is posted here: https://wiki.freepascal.org/Developing_Python_Modules_with_Pascal
However I cannot figure out how to configure this PyAPI-file to create a 64-bit-DLL that works with python 3.7.

Comment: But now the [Error 126] is gone? Which would mean the DLL loads fine and you're just trying to call an exported name the DLL doesn't have. Check in Dependency Walker, maybe the exported names change when switching to 64bit...

Comment: Or is the `OSError: [WinError 127]` a compiler error (it looked like Python to me), which means the DLL doesn't compile? Would make sense, since the C-API changed a lot between py2 and py3, so just exchanging the Python DLL probably won't be enough, which would mean that `PyAPI` doesn't support Python3.

Comment: Use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which module(s) are being accessed while the DLL is being loaded, and more importantly which module is missing. That may give you a clue to what needs fixing.

Comment: @Jeronimo it's a Python error. The DLL does compile correctly, but I cannot load it afterwards. I guess that PyAPI indeed doesn't support Python3, but is still able to compile. However it should be possible to somehow configure `PyAPI` to make it work with Python3 as well.

Comment: "How to create a 64 bit DLL in Delphi ..." Set the target platform to be 64 bit Windows. I'm sure this is documented.

Answer (score 0):

The module initialization changed quit a bit between Python2 and Python3, so just exchanging the DLL to a Python3 one won't work without also adapting the init code. There's a good [article](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/cporting.html?highlight=py_initmodule) about this in the docs, with a code example that includes the tricky part which I guess is the problem here:

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
#else
    PyObject *module = Py_InitModule("myextension", myextension_methods);
#endif
```

The `PyAPI` code you linked to uses `Py_InitModule4_64`, which doesn't exist (anymore) in Python3. That's what I guess causes the "procedure not found" error at runtime.

But also just exchanging this with another `external PythonLib name` won't do, because the whole invocation of the module init system is different. So I guess without actually fixing this `PyAPI` library to work with Python3, you're out of luck.

---

AFAIU, even if it worked your software stack would look something like this:

`Python` =**(ctypes loading)**=> `Delphi DLL` =**(embedding Python C-API)**=> `Python`

So a Python code loads a DLL via ctypes, which itself invokes the Python embedding system to again load and start the Python interpreter. Hard to say if this can work without trouble, in the end you said it did with Python2. But it seems a bit twisted from a software  architecture point of view...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't solve the problem yet, but gives me a better understanding of the problem :)

The point of the PyAPI library is that after renaming the DLL to .pyd I can directly import it and pass python-types to the DLL, i.e. I can use the Delphi functions in the DLL like any python function without loading ctypes in python. But maybe I should indeed rewrite it without use of PyAPI and instead passing ctypes from Python.